# Why my Suspense doesn't display my lazyloaded components?

Tags: reactjs

for my very first question here, it will probably be a stupid one, so please excuse it AND my English. I've created a simple React test app to check the React.lazy behaviour :

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
const LazyComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./lazycomponent'));

class LazyTest extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                    <LazyComponent />
                    Simple display
                </Suspense>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<LazyTest />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

with lazycomponent.js:

```
export function LazyComponent() {
    return <h1>test</h1>;
}
```

The "loading..." message appears a fraction of seconds, then the screen gets empty asif my LazyComponent was not displayed and even prevents "Simple display" text to be displayed. And indeed, if I remove my , the "Simple display" correctly appears after the "Loading..." message desappears. Could anyone be kind enough to let me know what is missing in LazyCompenent ?

Thank you very much in advance, and once again, sorry for such a basic problem.

Comment: How do you import your `LazyComponent`? is it with `const LazyComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./LazyComponent'));` ?

Comment: Yes. The code I display here is everything I have in that project right now (except, of course, the index.html which contains only the React container). I have to add that I'm quite new on js frameworks, and especially on React I'd like to learn for my next job).

Comment: Would be useful to see how you import the `LazyComponent` into your `App.js` because that could be the main issue. In addition, I found a simple example of lazy loading and re-did a little bit to make it easier to understand by removing useless stuff. you can find it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/new-forked-82fj1 .  Hope it helps

Comment: Dammit, I'm not even capable of doing a correct copy/paste, my bad. Original post updated. I'll have a look now on your code and try to understand why mine doesn't work...

Comment: Can you try making the child of Suspense a React Fragment?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion tobimori, but that doesn't work iether. It is asif, when React try to display my <LazyComponent />, something inside it prevented the whole Suspense (or, in your suggested case, React.Fragment) child from rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using not default export. Just change to:

```
export default function LazyComponent() {
    return <h1>test</h1>;
}
```

Comment: Ho mine ! How that single word have such an effect, I wonder O_O Thank you VERY much Max, I think I would have spent several more hours on this without you ! :)

Comment: And indeed, it is clearly written in the React doc, my bad :(
"React.lazy currently only supports default exports. If the module you want to import uses named exports, you can create an intermediate module that reexports it as the default."